# Problem with two improper integral problems.

Tags: calculus

In the first one I am supposed to just tell if the improper integral 
$$\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{\cos^2(x)}{x^2}\,dx$$
is convergent or divergent. I am not supposed to calculate the integral.

The best I can do is show that $$\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$$ is convergent and since that $$\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{\cos^2(x)}{x^2}\,dx\lt\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$$ and is there for also convergent. But I have a feeling that I am completely wrong on this one.

The other problem is: Is it possible that $$\int\limits_{-5}^{10} \cos(\tanh(x^2))\,dx =10\pi.$$ 
The teacher then gave a hint that don't even try to calculate the integral. On this problem I have no idea were to start.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: reasoning is right on the first integral. Cosine is bounded between -1 and 1, so its square is always less than or equal to 1.  It stands to reason (warning, hand waving) that the area under this curve will be less than the area under a curve who is known to converge.

Comment: $0<\tanh(x^2)<1$

Comment: You reasoning is not correct. see the difference.

Comment: $\cos x <= 1$  - then consider 15 x 1 = 15 < ?

Comment: @DemetriP we begin by comparing functions at first and then we integrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, you are right. But you should elaborate your proof.

Remember, there is a theorem that tells you that if $0<f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x>a$, then if the integral $$\int_a^\infty g(x)$$ converges, the integral $$\int_a^\infty f(x)$$ also converges.

For the second, a hint:

$\cos$ is bounded by $1$, and the length of the integral is $15$.

$10\cdot \pi$ is greater than $30$, on the other hand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was fun to find out I was correct on the first one and your hint help a lot.

Comment: replace $0<f(x)<g(x)$ by $0\leq f(x) \leq g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $-1 \leq \cos(x) \leq 1$.

There is a theorem that says that if $ m \leq f(x) \leq M$ then

$m(a - b) \leq \int_a^b f(x) \> dx \leq M(b-a) $.

Using this theorem,

$ \int_{-5}^{10} \cos(\tanh^2(x)) \> dx \leq 15 < 10 \pi$

We can conclude that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

since $\cos^2 x$ fluctuates between 0 & 1 hence
$$\frac{\cos^2 x}{x^2}<\frac{1}{x^2} \ \ (1<x<\infty)$$
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos^2 x}{x^2}<\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} \ \ (1<x<\infty)$$
but integral $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx$ converges hence by comparison test, integral $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos^2x}{x^2}dx$ also converges

Answer (score -1):

Let $f$ defined by

$f(x)=\frac{cos^2(x)}{x^2}$.

$f$ is continuous at $ [1,+\infty)$

and

$(\forall x\geq 1) \;   0\leq f(x) \leq\frac{1}{x^2}$

but

$\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}$

is convergent , so

$\int_1^{+\infty}f(x)dx$

is also convergent.